# Pubcenter Ad is not clickable

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, ads, direct3d

I'm bashing my head with weird problem, the ads from microsoft pubcenter are not clickabkle when
application uses D3D/XAML interop.
BUT I see many games on windows store that have pubcenter ads and clearly uses d3d/xaml - how to make those two to work together ?

Simple steps to reproduce the problem:
(VS2013 - with all the latest updates, pibcenter ctrl also updated to latest version)

VS2013 -> New -> Project -> (Visual C++ / Store Apps) -> DirectX and XAML App (Windows phone)

(NOTE: This is Windows phone 8.1 app, ***NOT*** windows phone 8.1 silverlight app)

when the project is created, just go to DirectXPage.xaml

and edit it to look as follow:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AdTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI"
    x:Class="AdTest.DirectXPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <SwapChainPanel x:Name="swapChainPanel">

        <!-- Grid definition, to place ad on bottom (may remove if no ads) -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Hello from XAML!"
HorizontalAlignment="Right"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
FontSize="30" />

        <UI:AdControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="adBanner" AutoRefreshIntervalInSeconds="60" ApplicationId="xxxxxxxxxxx" AdUnitId="xxxxx" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="320"/>

    </SwapChainPanel>

    <!-- Uncomment this if using the app bar in your phone application.
  <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Play" AutomationProperties.Name="Sample Button" 
                            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="SampleAppBarButton" Click="AppBarButton_Click" />
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>-->
</Page>
```

replace xxxxx with real app / unit ids and run the sample - now when the banner shows up, try to click on it -- it does not work :/
Is there any way to make it clickable ? (it's not covered by any other controll, it gets it's input properly, so I do not know what the issue may be).

Comment: Just try adding your `AdControl` right after the `SwapChainPanel`.

Comment: nope, this does not work to, if I remove TextBlock (so AdControl is the only one inside SwapChainPanel it is still not clickable) - did you tried and it works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you solve your problem?
IT seems that this is related with it being a c++ app, I am also with a lot of problems with it.
One workaround that I found was to ad the method Tapped into the control:

```
    adPubcenter->Tapped += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedEventHandler(this, &OpenGLESPage::OnAdTapped);


void OpenGLESPage::OnAdTapped(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e){
```

And then

```
void OpenGLESPage::OnAdTapped(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e){
    //Handle touch yourself (ie. opens a game that you have)
    Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchUriAsync(ref new Uri("http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=bb8d4ce2-1853-47b6-9b0d-bb1af5a07436"));
}
```

At least this way the ad does something when clicked.